# What is this horizontal line in the scroller of Adium's conversation window?

Tags: macos, adium

Sometimes a horizontal red line will appear in the scroller area of my [Adium](https://adium.im) conversation windows.  When it appears, nothing unusual or interesting is happening.  I am not searching for anything, not selecting anything and not using any 'special' feature.

[image: Red horizontal line in Adium scroller]

I have consulted the documentation but it doesn't seem to mention the line at all.

Does anyone know what this line indicates or what function it serves?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use Adium, but from other UI elements I've seen elsewhere it might represent a selected item, or a positive hit on a search (multiple lines sometimes for multiple hits,) perhaps it is the last conversation read or replied to. Perhaps it represents the current time in relation to the times in the data to the left - Google Calendar has a thin line indicating the time. _What is it about the data to the left of the line that would make it important?_

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks. Typically nothing unusual is going on when it happens.  I am not searching for anything, not selecting anything and no special event has happened.